# Passing values between cucumber statements

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash

I'm running in to an issue in that I need to get one value in a cucumber statement, and then give that value to another statement.

Specifically I am getting a JSON object from one page (where that object gets sent to an api endpoint as a preference) and then using information out of that after I query the api, which happens in a completely separate step.

I am suspecting that I have to write the value somewhere, and then pull that value when the step that needs it comes up, but I'm kind of at a loss for doing that as well.

I can provide any further needed details, thanks for any help!

Comment: I know this is probably a rookie question - it's something I haven't had to deal with yet though and I'm not yet finding the documentation I need online.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a rookie question - to which the answer is to use instance variables - @variable_name = get_method in the helper method your step calls.